# My media queries not applying to mobile device. Is my code wrong in some way?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am not sure why my media queries are not working on the mobile phone. When I slide the desktop version to be narrow like a mobile phone, the smaller tablet and mobile views seem to work. But they do not work on an actual device. Is something wrong my my code?

Site here: http://jenniferblatzdesign.com/.

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gabriela');

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    bottom: 30px;
}
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
body {
  background: #fcfcfc url('bg.png'); /* http://subtlepatterns.com/crossword/ */
  font-size: 62.5%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 45px 25px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
/* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Basic Styles */
body {
    background-color: #ece8e5;
}
nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 94%;
    background: #0068ac;
    font-size: 1.5 em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #283744;
}
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 40px;
}
nav li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
nav a {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;
}
nav li a {
    border-right: none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #89a8bc;
}
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#header h1 {    
        display: none;
}
#header h2 {
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    line-height: 1.9em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 200;
}
    #header img {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#footer p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#content #footer p a {
    color: #005496;
}
#footer ul li a {
    color: #005496;
}
#footer ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#about h3 {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2.2em;
}
#praise h3 {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2.7em;
}
#about p {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
#about p a {
    color: #005496;
}
#praise p {
    width: 70%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: #474646;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#praise h5 {
    padding-left: 40px;
    color: #4C3B5F;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
#praise h6 {
    padding-left: 56px;
    color: #474646;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}
#praise hr   {
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30x;
    color: #7B7979;
}
#about {
    width: 70%;
}
#contact h3 {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2.2em;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#header p {
    color: #4C3B5F;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-top: -30px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
#contact p {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
#contact p a {
    color: #005496;
}
#social h3 {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2.2em;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#social h2 img {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#social {
    width: 90%;
}
#linkedin h2 a {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#twitter h2 a {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#behance h2 a {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#facebook h2 a {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#pinterest h2 a {
    color: #005496;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Styles for screen 600px and lower*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { 
        height: auto;
        width: 94%;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
width: 20%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 5px;
    }
    #header img {
    width: 90%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#header h2 {
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
}

/*Styles for screen 515px and lower*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 94%;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: #ece8e5;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav a#pull:after {
        content:"";
        background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
    #header img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#praise p {
    width:95%;
}
#about {
    width: 100%;
}
}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;

    }
}

br { display: block; line-height: 1.6em; } 

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ol, ul { list-style: none; }

input, textarea { 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
strong, b { font-weight: bold; }

strong, b { font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif}
em, i { font-style: italic; }

table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
img { border: 0; max-width: 100%; }

h1 {
  font-family: 'Gabriela', Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.7em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.55em;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #514b53;
  letter-spacing: -0.06em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

/** page structure **/
#wrapper {
  display: block;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#portfolio {
  display: block;
}

#portfolio li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#portfolio li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.mfp-title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #ddd !important;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/** clearfix **/
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }

html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }


/** media queries **/
@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  #portfolio li {
    width: 45%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  #portfolio { 
    text-align: center;
  }

  #portfolio li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example please? No one wants to look at your entire CSS document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely has to do with your Viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag